# Why is bokeh show(plot) not working?

Tags: python-3.x, graph, widget, interactive, bokeh

I am trying myself out at Bokeh. I find it quite entertaining as it seems a nice alternative to D3js. In a first little attempt, I want to create a little interactive circle chart with widget (for changing the title and maybe glyph color/size). Here is what I do:

```
# interactive widget bokeh figure
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, TextInput
from bokeh.plotting import figure
import numpy as np

        # data
x = [-4, 3, 2, 4, 10, 11, -2, 6]
y = [-3, 2, 2, 9, 11, 12, -5, 6]    


        # Set up plotting

x_top = np.max(x)+np.var(x)
x_bottom = np.min(x)-np.var(x)
y_top = np.max(y)+np.var(y)
y_bottom = np.min(y)-np.var(y)

p = figure(plot_height=400, plot_width=400, title="a little interactive chart",         
                tools="crosshair,pan,reset,save,wheel_zoom",
                x_range=[x_bottom, x_top], y_range=[y_bottom, y_top])

p.circle(x, y, fill_color="red", line_color="red", size=6)


        # Set up widgets
text = TextInput(title="title", value='a little interavtive chart')
size = Slider(title="circle size", value = 6, start=0, end=10, step=0.1)


        # Set up callbacks
def update_title(attrname, old, new):
    p.title.text = text.value

text.on_change('value', update_title)

# # Set up layouts and add to document
inputs = widgetbox(text, size)

curdoc().add_root(row(inputs, p, width=800))
curdoc().title = "Sliders"

show(p)
```

Somehow, I get no visual result - no errors, yet no result. My hunge is that I'm using `curdoc()` wrongly. Any ideas on why I get an empty plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are creating bokeh applications using python callbacks and `curdoc` as you seem to be doing, then you don't run them with the python interpreter directly. You have to run them with the Bokeh server:

```
bokeh serve --show myapp.py
```

Comment: Thanks! How does that work? I simply added `bokeh serve --show myapp.py` as comand in the end - and I get an error. What do I need to do instead?

Comment: Is there a possibility to circumvent the comand prompt and use `show(plot)` instead?

Comment: Not really, if you want to have real python callbacks. That is to say: not really, if you want a *Bokeh application*. It is possible to start the bokeh server from a script using the `subprocess` module, but to run a Bokeh app, you have to start a Bokeh server somehow. Otherwise, if you want a standalone Bokeh document, you can use `output_file` and `show` which is demonstrated all throughout the [project documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/index.html), for instance http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/quickstart.html#getting-started

Comment: Additionally, it's possible to have sophisticated *javascript callbacks* in standalone documents (i.e. without the server). See: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#userguide-interaction-callbacks

Comment: Thank you! I am on the documentation as I write :)